# How to download an image from the app's assets folder with Capacitor so that it's accessible in the Photos App in iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want the user to be able download images from the project `/assets` folder into an external publically accessible folder. This works fine on Android but in iOS everything saves under the app's unique ID directory so not sure if this possible. Essentially I want the user to save a photo from inside the app and then be able to open it easily from within their phone's default Photos app.

With the final `photoPath` var in the code below I can display the image in a `<img` tag using the DomSanitizer. Though still not sure how to make the file accessible on the user's system from outside the app.

```
        this.http.get('/assets/img/' + item.img, { responseType: 'blob' })
            .subscribe(res => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = () => {
                    var base64data = reader.result;

                    await Filesystem.appendFile({
                        data: base64data.toString(),
                        path: item.file,
                        directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents
                    })

                    const finalPhotoUri = await Filesystem.getUri({
                            directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
                            path: item.file
                        });

                        let photoPath = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(finalPhotoUri.uri);
                        console.log("Photo Path: ", photoPath);

                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(res);
                console.log(res);
            });
```

Comment: You need a plugin for writing in the gallery